# Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: magento2.3, database, data-migration-tool, foreign-key-constraint

the following error as seen in the screenshot came up during the data migration from M1 to M2 using data migration tool. Please share your views as to how I go about eliminating this error with a brief explanation. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CAUSE**

There are missing database records in the `parent_table` to which the `field_id` of the `child_table` is pointing to.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

Delete the records from the `child_table`, if you do not need them.

To keep the records, disable the Data Integrity Step by modifying the Data Migration Tool's `config.xml`

And more refer this link :-

**https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033020451**

Any query let me know

Comment: @yes, will do as advised.

Comment: okay not problem and any query let me know... thanks

Comment: sure, will post whenever I need help with something post thorough research on SE.